# Client-Server communication between Raspberry Pi and Android

Tags: java, android, c++, client-server

I am trying to setup a client-server system with the Pi acting as the server, and the Android device being the client. Every time I run the code (I cobbled together from the internet) the client throws an IOException:

```
 Connection timed out: connect
```

I just discovered that when I try to ping the Pi's IP it is unreachable.
How can I fix this?

Note I am currently testing Java code on a Windows PC until I get it working.

Client Code (Java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class client
{
static Socket clientSocket;
static String homeIp="192.168.0.105"; //internal ip of server (aka Pi in this case)
static int port=4242; 
public static void main(String [] args)    
 {
   sendToPi("I sent a message");
 }

public static void sendToPi(String s)
{
//wordsList.append("in sendToPi()\n");
System.out.println("in sendToPi()");
//Log.e("aaa","in sendToPi()\n");
try {
clientSocket = new Socket(homeIp, port);
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
out.println(s);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
//Log.e("aaa","Don't know about host: "+homeIp+"."+e.getMessage());
System.out.println("Don't know about host: "+homeIp+"."+e.getMessage());
//System.exit(1);
} catch (IOException e) {
//Log.e("aaa","Couldn't get I/O for the connection to:         "+homeIp+"."+e.getMessage());
System.out.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: "+homeIp+"."+e.getMessage());
//System.exit(1);
}
}
}
```

Server Code (C): I used code from [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f00/www/class24code/echoserver.c) exactly as written. compiled as server. Started with ./server 4242

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. Any idea why it isnt working?

Comment: `static String homeIp="localhost";` - You need to give ip of raspberry pi device. With your current code, Android device is attempting to connect to port 4242 on the same mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to explicitly forward the client port in my router.